# Getting same value while comparing 2 arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, compare

- I can able to fetch json response , added response in arraylist
- When i try to compare 2 arraylist , arraylist2 value is not changing.
- what i have done :

**json parsing :**

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    id = obj.getString("alert_id");


                    map.put("alert_id", id);

                    Log.d("map", map.toString());
                    arraylist1.add(map);

                       Log.e("asdasd", arraylist1.toString());
                }
```

**- Comparision :**

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arraylist1.size(); j++) {
                    if (!(arraylist.get(i).get("id")).equals((arraylist1.get(j).get("id")))) {
                        //Checking whether the last value in the list..
                        if (j == (arraylist1.size() - 1)) {
                            unCommonList.add(arraylist.get(i).get("alert_id"));


                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**-- Output :**

```
92 79
91 79
86 79
85 79
84 79
81 79
80 79
```

-- **Everytime arraylist2 remains same, arraylist1 is changing, but arraylist2 value is not**

-- This is my arraylist2 :

```
[{abcd=100, id=79, createdate=2016-03-14 03:59:43, defge=2012310, 123123xyzw=alpha}, {abcd=11230, id=79, createdate=2016-03-14 03:59:43, defge=201231230, xyzw=alpasdha}, {abcd=10452430, id=79, createdate=2016-03-14 03:59:43, defge=12346, xyzw=alasdpha}, {abcd=1za00, id=79, createdate=2016-03-14 03:59:43, defge=212312300, xyzw=alpdsaha}, {abcd=112312300, id=79, createdate=2016-03-14 03:59:43, defge=21231200, xyzw=alpsqwha}, {abcd=123123, id=79, createdate=2016-03-14 03:59:43, defge=201231230, xyzw=alpqwreha}, {abcd=112312300, id=79, createdate=2016-03-14 03:59:43, defge=212312300, xyzw=alpyjha}, {abcd=101231230, id=79, createdate=2016-03-14 03:59:43, defge=200, xyzw=alpha}]
```

Comment: unCommonList.add(arraylist.get(j).get("alert_id"));

Comment: You forgot what you want compare ? asc /desc?

Comment: @Ajay Pandya , can u show demo ? plz

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara , 2nd arraylist value is not changing.

Comment: First i  want to know what you want to achieve ?

Comment: i want to compare 2 arraylist , and get elements which are uncommon

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arraylist1.size(); j++) {
                if (!(arraylist.get(i).get("id")).equals((arraylist1.get(j).get("id")))) {
                    //Checking whether the last value in the list..
                    if (j == (arraylist1.size() - 1)) {
                        unCommonList.add(arraylist.get(i).get("alert_id"));


                    } else {

                    }
                }else{
                           break;
                              }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so for getting unmatch element you can try this code

```
ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();


for (Person person2 : arrayList2) {

    boolean found = false;
    for (Person person1 : arrayList1) {
    if (person2.id == person1.id) {
        found = true;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    results.add(person2.id);
}
}
```

Comment: what if my arraylist contains other elements also ?

Comment: Same way found=true only if require elements found

Comment: Have you try it with my code? because found boolean is vital for adding element.

Comment: have u seen my arraylist Log, every id is same

Comment: and what about this person2.id ? what should i mention here ?

Comment: Actually that is second arraylist's element,Above code will compare two list and return unmatch id from list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106709/discussion-between-tiger-and-ajay-pandya).